# Matlab: Input Directly a Matrix into a Cell from an Address

Tags: matlab

How could I input directly a matrix into a cell that has been loaded from an address? For example, if `Response` is defined as a cell:

```
Response(1,1)={load (['sourceETA/Tn',num2str(period*10),'/ETdisp.txt'])};
```

But the above code doesn't work! What should I do?!

Comment: Could you please clarify what "doesn't work"?  Any error messages and/or expected output vs. generated output would also be good.

Comment: I faced this error: Undefined variable "load" or class "load".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a space between load and first parentheses?
Try removing the space:

```
Response(1,1)={load(['sourceETA/Tn',num2str(period*10),'/ETdisp.txt'])};
```